# Angularjs filter consuming and returning object: Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'd like to create a custom angularjs [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#filter)  that consumes and returns an object. Code below fails in infinite digestion loop. What causes the problem and what are possible solutions?

```js
angular.module('app', [])

angular.module('app')
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
      word: 'world'
    }
  }])
  
angular.module('app')
  .component('myComp', {
    template: '<em>word: {{$ctrl.param.word}}</em>',
    bindings: {
      param: '<',
    }
  })
  
angular.module('app')
  .filter('greet', function () {
    return function (object) {
      return {
        word: 'Hello ' + object.word
      }
    }
  })

angular
  .bootstrap(document.querySelector('#app'), ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <my-comp param="obj | greet" ></my-comp>
</div>
```

I've noticed that if filter input is an object literal, everything works ok. So it doesn't seem to have direct relation to returning new object every time the filter is called as suggested at [infdig](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10) error doc page.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

angular.module('app')
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
      word: 'world'
    }
  }])
  
angular.module('app')
  .component('myComp', {
    template: '<em>word: {{$ctrl.param.word}}</em>',
    bindings: {
      param: '<',
    }
  })
  
angular.module('app')
  .filter('greet', function () {
    return function (object) {
      return {
        word: 'Hello ' + object.word
      }
    }
  })

angular
  .bootstrap(document.querySelector('#app'), ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <my-comp param="{ word: 'foo' } | greet" ></my-comp>
</div>
```

Comment: You catually answered your self... And when you pass object literal to filter, it is once calculated and thats it. It does not create watch on any variable. Considering solution - do not write such filters.

Comment: Are you asking about how to fix the `infdig` error? Or are you asking for an explaination of the AngularJS stateless filter optimization?